$R_{\mathcal{N}}$ is not locally connected
[From 'Counterexamples in Topology']1

Let $\tau$ be the supremum topology of the usual topology $\tau_1$ and the cocountable topology $\tau_2$; show that $(\mathbb{R}; \tau)$ is not locally connected.

Considering $A=]-\infty;1[-\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$; we have $\mathscr{C}_0=]-\infty;0] \notin \tau$ as if $\mathscr{C}_0=]-\infty;0]$ were in $\tau$:
$$]-\infty;0]=U-C;  \ \textit{U open; C countable}  $$
then $]-\epsilon;\epsilon[ \subset U$ for some $\epsilon >0$ but $]0; \epsilon[-C\neq\emptyset$.
So $]-\infty;0]$ is not open and there doesn't exist any connected neighborhood of $0$ that is a subset of the open neighborhood $A$, which leads to the conclusion that there is no local basis for $0$.
Which argument should I use in order to show that $]-\infty;0]$ is connected ?

See here for a proof that $([0,1], \tau)$ (or, similarly, $(\mathbb R , \tau)$, $((-\infty, 0], \tau)$) are connected.
